# Loop Through a String and return just one character in Java

Tags: java, for-loop

so I'm developing this Java program which I need to iterate through a string of character and I just want to return back a character in which it contains (F or f or S or s or B or b or or L or l) in which if there is duplicate of the character found in the string it just take take ealiest character found. I'm just a beginner so please help me. this is what I can have so far. Thanks for your time

command ="France";

```
public static char CommandRestrictor (String command)   
{

    for(int i=0; i<command.length();i++)
    {
        char result=command.charAt(i); //set variable character char_bin to binary value in place of i

        if(result=='F'||result=='f'||result=='L'||result=='l'||result=='S'||result=='s'||result=='B'||result=='b'||result=='r'||result=='R') {
            return ;
        }
        else {
            return 'f';
        }




}
    return result;
}
```

input result: "France";
output result: 'F'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your result variable is instantiated within the for loop, and so it is only accessible within the for loop. I would suggest the following:

```
public static char CommandRestrictor (String command)   
{
    char result = 'f';

    for(int i = 0; i < command.length(); i++)
    {            
        if(command.charAt(i)=='F'||command.charAt(i)=='f'||
           command.charAt(i)=='L'||command.charAt(i)=='l'||
           command.charAt(i)=='S'||command.charAt(i)=='s'||
           command.charAt(i)=='B'||command.charAt(i)=='b'||
           command.charAt(i)=='r'||command.charAt(i)=='R') 
        {
            result = command.charAt(i);
            break;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

EDIT: Silly mistake. My if loop conditions said result=='F' rather than command.charAt(i)=='F'.

Comment: hi, i tried your code but somehow it just return 'f' no matter what. even if the there is l it will just return ''f'

Comment: i mean if for example "lf" is the input it returns 'f' but what I want is it to return 'l' because l comes first.

Answer (score 1):

Do it as follows:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] testStrs = { "A football", "A Football", "A lamp", "A ball", "A Ball" };
        for (String str : testStrs) {
            System.out.println(commandRestrictor(str));
        }
    }

    public static char commandRestrictor(String command) {
        char ch = '\0';
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[FfSsBbLl]");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(command);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            ch = command.charAt(matcher.start());
        }
        return ch;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
f
F
l
b
B
```